# Gabor filter implementation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, gabor-filter

I have implemented a bank of Gabor filter, but it doesn't work correctly. Can anyone please help me to solve the problem.
This is the code I have implemented:

```
Img=imread('21_training.tif');
Green =  Img( : , : , 2);
Inverted_Green_Channel = 255-Green;
figure, imshow(Inverted_Green_Channel); title('Inverted_Green_Channel');

My_New_Gabor = cell (1,9);
k=1;

Wavelength = [1.5,2.5,3.5];
scales = [3,5,7];
Teta = -15;
N = 12;
bw = 1;
GaborArray = cell(1,1, N);

m=39;
n=39;

%creating the bank
for p = 1 : size (Wavelength,2)
    for t =1 : size (scales,2)
        for f = 1 : N
            Teta = Teta + 15;
            for x = 1: m
                for y = 1:n
                    G(x,y) = exp (-(x^2 + y^2)/(2*(scales(t)^2)))* exp ((1i*pi)/(Wavelength(p)*scales(t))*(x*sin (Teta)- y*cos (Teta)));
                end
            end
            %figure, imshow(G);
            GaborArray{p,t,f} = G;
        end
        Teta = -15;
    end
end


%convolving and getting the maximum
for p = 1 : 3
    for t =1 : 3
        for f = 1 : 12
            gb=  GaborArray{p,t,f};
            im1 = imfilter(Inverted_Green_Channel, gb,'replicate','conv');
            im1 = abs ( double( im1 ));
            if(f == 1)
                Max_Mat = im1;
            else
                Max_Mat = max ( Max_Mat , im1 );
            end

            figure,imshow ( Max_Mat,[] );
            GaborArray{p,t,f}=[];
        end
        My_New_Gabor{1,k} = Max_Mat;

        k=k+1;
        clear im1;
        clear Mat_Mat;
    end
end
```

Here is my input image :

[image]

Comment: no answer !! please help me :((((

Comment: "It doesn't work" does not tell us anything. How exactly is your code failing? Does it give errors when you run it? Does it produce an image that you didn't expect? If so, what is the output and how does it differ from the desired results? What have you done to debug the problem?

Comment: there is no error, but it produces wrong output. I expect the output to be similar to the input image, but with white vessels and black background. I don't get this output.